# Request for hint or guidance for exercise in series $\sum _{i=1}^\infty \frac 1 k e_k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

$$\sum _{i=1}^{\infty}\frac 1 k e_k$$

where $e_k = \underbrace{(0,\ldots,1}_k,0,\ldots )$,

Prove that series converges to sequence $(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\ldots)$ in $C_0$.

I know that since $\frac{1}{k}e_k \in C_0 \Rightarrow \lim_k \frac{1}{k}e_k = 0$.

And also $\|\frac{1}{k}e_k\| = 1$.

While looking at series, it is obvious that

$$\sum _{i=1}^\infty \frac 1 k e_k = (1,0,0,\ldots) + \left( 0, \frac 1 2, 0, 0, \ldots \right) + (0,0,\frac{1}{3},0,\ldots) + \cdots$$

But I don't have enough time to write infinite amount of terms and then add them together.

What can be used to reasonably show this addition ? Cauchy sequences perhaps, since it was taught in our course ?

Comment: You just need to show that the norm of the difference converges to 0

Comment: "converges in $C_o$" has to mean it's about some particular kind of convergence, probably either convergence with respect to a particular norm or else pointwise convergence. What space is $C_o\text{?} \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy with respect to $C_0$.

It's $C_0$, not $C_o$. Edited the OP

Comment: Anyway, what is the norm? Are you sure that $|| \frac{1}{k}e_k || = 1$

Comment: @Adam The norm of $C_0$, which is $(\xi_k): \sup_k \xi_k$

Comment: @flowian look at Michaels answer, you basically need to show that $\frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notation $\displaystyle \sum_{i\,=\,1}^n \frac 1 k e_k$ rather than $\displaystyle \sum_{k\,=\,1}^n \frac 1 k e_k$ or $\displaystyle \sum_{i\,=\,1}^n \frac 1 i e_i$ seems unfortunate.

Since you wrote an expression involving a norm, you have in mind some particular norm, although you did not tell us which one. So you need to show that
$$
\left\| \lim_{n\,\to\,\infty} \left( \left( \sum_{k\,=\,1}^n \frac 1 k e_k\right) - \left( 1, \frac 1 2, \frac 1 3, \ldots \right) \right)\right\| =0.
$$
Observe that
\begin{align}
& \left( \sum_{k\,=\,1}^n \frac 1 k e_k \right) - \left( 1, \frac 1 2, \frac 1 3, \ldots \right) \\[10pt]
= {} & \Big( \,\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_n, \frac 1 {n+1}, \frac 1 {n+2}, \frac 1 {n+3}, \ldots \Big)
\end{align}
So you need to say something about the **norm** of that last vector. The norm is a positive number. So you have an infinite sequence of positive numbers. The problem is to show that the limit of that sequence of positive numbers is $0.$

Comment: The norm is of $C_0$, which is $(\xi_k): \sup_k \xi_k$

Comment: @flowian : So $$ \Big\| \Big( \,\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_n, \frac 1 {n+1}, \frac 1 {n+2}, \frac 1 {n+3}, \ldots \Big) \Big\| = \text{which positive number?} $$

Comment: since $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac 1 n \rightarrow 0$$
Therefore $$\sup_n (0,0, \dots) = 0$$